Angular V18, missing the environments folder
I recreate a reference application for each new version of Angular before upgrading my Angular applications.  I have a whole defined process to create the demo application.  I use the following to create my reference application:
 ng new demo-mg18 --routing --skip-git --standalone false --style css

In running through the instructions, I found no environments folder and the main.ts missing the import.   I don't see any option in ng new command.  So, what's up?  Do I have to add environments feature manually?

Environment files were removed in v15 from the default setup.
You can easily create them using the schematics : ng g environments

Thanks, I've added the above to my instructions to create the reference application.

From Angular 18 onwards angular dev team has removed the environment file/folder by default. The latest changes in angular 18 now encourage to use of Angular built-in configuration options in the angular.json file for managing different environments.

Refer the full change log here

However, still you can add the environment file by following the below steps:
create environment folder and create separate file for environment.ts file for separate environments like below:
// environment.qa.ts
export const environment = { 
      production: false,
      apiUrl: 'https://api.qa.example.com'
};
     


// environment.prod.ts        
export const environment = { 
      production: true,
      apiUrl: 'https://api.example.com'
};

Update angular.json file under configurations and replace part under production replace it as below
"production": {
   "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ]
}

After that update the main.ts file like below and import the environment.ts file like below:
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

You can now verify the above solution via ng serve or ng build --configuration production

How does angular.json add configuration variables?

via file replacement in the above angular.json
